# C# search DataTable performance

Tags: c#, performance, datatable

I would like to know if there are ways to make this run faster. Not a big concern right now, but I would like to think long term, it might be important.

This is C#, and I can not change the input parameters data types, but basically I have to make something like the SQL: `SELECT returnCol FROM dt WHERE ColName = ColValue`

As the datatable itself: it has more than 100 columns, but it should not too many rows, usually ~10 rows but it can spike up to 100 rows sometimes. This is part of a data parse that is happening once a minute, that is why I am trying to see if there are ways for enhancement.

```
private string FindInT(DataTable dt, string ColName, string ColValue, string returnCol)
{
    if (dt == null) return "";
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ColName)) return "";
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ColValue)) return "";
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnCol)) return "";

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        if (row[ColName].ToString().ToLower().Trim() == ColValue.ToLower().Trim())
        {
            return row[returnCol].ToString();
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: If your code works and you seek improvement or constructive critique, your question is more appropriate on [codereview.se]

Comment: Are all columns string columns? Why do you use a `DataTable` and not a `List<CustomClass>`? Why do you return an empty string if someone passes `null` as `DataTable`?

Comment: Seems like a filter would be more appropriate